# Suma de 2 mitades de un número par en C

Tags: c

¿Cómo puedo separar las cifras de un número par (con número de cifras par) en 2 mitades para luego sumarlas?
Por ejemplo 81. 8+1=9, pero que valga para 2, 4, 6, 8,... cifras.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
     int num_intro; //número introducido
     int num_suma; //número obtenido al sumar la primera mitad de las crifras con la segunda

     printf("Introduce un numero que tenga un numero de cifras par: ");
     scanf("%d", &num_intro);

     num_suma= //suma de las dos mitades (¿?)

     printf ("La suma de las dos mitades es: %d", num_suma);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Cuenta las cifras. 2) Divide cada número por la mitad del valor contado. 3) Suma.

Comment: ¿Con un 12345678 tendría que ser 1234 + 5678?

Comment: @CandidMoe exacto.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster No entiendo. ¿Para qué me sirve dividir cada número?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hacer? Coloca el código o pseudo código que tengas y así es posible que tengas ayuda.

Comment: @ÁlvaroValverde Yo tampoco lo entiendo, es tu requerimiento: quieres dividir el número en dos partes y sumarlas.

Comment: @FernandoCarraro ya está. Gracias

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Si, quiero dividir las el número en 2 partes para luego sumarlas, pero, de que me sirve dividir cada dígito?? Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el valor inicial es un `int`, lo convierto a string usando `sprintf`, lo cual me permite separarlo en dos mitades.

A continuación convierto cada mitad a `int` y luego sumo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int numero = 12345678;
    char buffer[10];
    
    sprintf(buffer, "%d", numero);
    int largo = strlen(buffer);
    int num2 = atoi(buffer + largo / 2);
    buffer[largo / 2] = 0;
    int num1 = atoi(buffer);
    printf("%d + %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 + num2);
}
```

produce

```
1234 + 5678 = 6912
```